# SSL Redirect in VirtualHost causing url to break

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, https

I recently configured by website to direct all traffic through https. I did this by modifying the vhost file to show this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/example"
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine when I go to the root of the site i.e. example.com,  however when I try to go to a subdirectory I get a weird break in the url. For example if I type example.com/blog it tries to redirect to https://example.comblog. What is going on here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error if the `Redirect` line become `Redirect permanent / https://example.com` (e.g without trailing slash). With your configuration above, the redirection works properly.

Comment: I tried removing the trailing / and using `RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ https:/example.com/$1` and neither worked.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the problem by changing:

```
https://example.com/
```

to

```
https://example.com\/
```

This seems to have solved the problem, I assume that at some point Apache stripped off the slash.

Answer (score 1):

For redirecting a TLS/SSL site to a non-TLS site, see the details below:

Adding a trailing slash, and escaping it with a backslash restores the missing slash.

I found that my particular site needed the redirect in both virtual hosts  (*:80 and *:443) but the TLS one was not working properly. The following added to both virtual hosts fixed the issue.

```
Redirect permanent "/" http://example.com\/
```

Note: The apache documentation shows adding quotes around everything. In my case the above worked just fine, allowing pages in the URL to be resolved as expected. 
Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/avoid.html

Examples extrapolated from Source:

`Redirect "/one/" "http://one.example.com/"`
`Redirect permanent "/" "http://example.com/"`

Hope this helps someone.